How to define an array to use inside a computed?
I need to have a ref that will hold an array for my Vue 3 app written using composition API and typescript.
The array is used in a computed where I will push in some objects. At the moment I'm unable to achieve this I will get this error on push when I target the array in computed

Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Ref<[]>'

This is the code I'm using:
const myArray = ref<[]>([]);

const myComputed = computed(() => {
  if (propertyOne) {
    myArray.push({ id: 'autoId0', path: 'myPath' })
  }
  return myArray
})

I've also tried by using a let myArray = [] inside the computed but will be not populated. Any suggestions?

The array is the value of the ref, which isn't itself an array.

So how I can correcty define it?can you show an example?

Computed usually are derived values and are free from any mutations. If your derived value is an array with extra value based on a critieria, copy the array, mutate that, and return that instead. Relevant docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#best-practices

@captainskippah so basically I can't populate the array inside the computed right?

Let's first address your error of:

Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Ref<[]>'

Consider these examples:
const stringValue: string = ''
const numberValue: number = 123

If you don't explicitly add the type, typescript will use the implied type based on the initial value i.e
const impliedStringType = ''
const impliedNumberType = 123

That being said if you do:
const myArrayRef = ref([])

The implied type is Ref<[]>
Type Ref is NOT an array but an "object" containing an array.
Docs about Ref:

https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state-1

To get the actual value from a ref, you access it via the value property.
Thus to make push work:
myArrayRef.value.push()


Next to address your usage of computed,
Computed usually are derived values and are free from any mutations.
If your derived value is an array with extra value based on a critieria, copy the array, mutate that, and return that instead.
Docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#best-practices
In other words:
const myArrayRef = ref([])

const myComputedArray = computed(() => {
  // Regular array. Not a Ref.
  // A new array with values from the original array.
  const computedArray = [...myArrayRef.value]

  if (criteria) {
    computedArray.push(123)
  }

  return computedArray
})

Otherwise, what you are doing is whenever the criteria is met, the original array gets push.
So if the following scenario happens:

Criteria: true
Criteria: false
Criteria: true

Your original array now has 2 new values because you are mutating the original array.

Here is a simple Vue Playground demo and another using object Vue Playground demo

mainly it's a static array that I will mutate in a watcher when a conditions is meet. Inside the computed I will just need to define the array entries. Thank you for the suggestion I will need to test.

Depending on your use-case, watcher might actually be what you need. Do note that even if your array is static, you might still want to use Ref so that when you mutated it, Vue can detect the update and also computed is not writable by default and it won't react if it's not reading any reactive values such as Ref like I just explained which makes you still need to use Ref.

The computed will populate a dropdown menu with desired items. The only mutation the array will have is to detect when the route.path will changhe so I will use v-model to set the current selected item instead of the placeholder of the dropdown

tested as you've suggested by declaring ref([]) but will give an error if I try to push objects inside the array. Also if I add curly brackets in the square of ref, I'm unable to get the elements of the menù and the dropdown will be not rendered because I'm checking if the value returned from the computed have a lenght different from 0

Added a link to a Vue Playground demo of this scenario to be clear.

saw it, but the example will push single values, I have objects to push into the array.

updated to use object as values being pushed

I see in the example you've added the initial values to the ref, if I define an empty object and then push the elements into it will be this like the bad example?
